# C++ VALGRIND Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation

Tags: c++, heap-memory, valgrind

I have a problem. When I compile the program I don't have any errors, but when I use valgrind:
Uninitialized value was created by a heap allocation (line with new)
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s)(line with delete)
I search through the forums however I didn't find much information which could help me. 
I would be really grateful for a hint.

My program

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <istream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>



using namespace std;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int dlugosc,miejsce;
ifstream file;


class channel
{
public:
  int start;
  double length;
  int bytespix;
  int resolution;
  channel(double g) : start(g),
                        length(0),
                        bytespix(0),
                        resolution(0)
    {
    }  

};
int fileopen() // opens the file and returns its size
{
   file.open ("0_dlc.000", ios::in|ios::binary);

  if( file.good() == true )
    {
      cout << "Uzyskano dostep do pliku!" << endl;
    }
  else 
    {
      cout<< "File cannot open" <<endl;
    }

  file.seekg(0, file.end);
  dlugosc = file.tellg();

  return dlugosc;
}

int findword(const char* slowo,int startplace) 
{
  int m;
  int c=0;
  int cur=0;
  unsigned int equal=0;
  char element=0;

  file.seekg (startplace, file.beg);

  for(m=0;m<dlugosc;m++)
  {

  file.get(element); 

   if(element==slowo[cur])
   {
    equal++;
    cur++;
   }
   else
   {
     equal=0;
     cur=0;
     if(element==slowo[cur])
     {
       equal++;
       cur++;

     }
   }
   if(equal==strlen(slowo))
   {
     return m+startplace; 
   } 

  }
  return 0;  


}

int findvalue(const char* wartosc,int startpoint)
{
    int p;
    int g;
    char element=0;
    char* buffer = new char[9];

    miejsce = findword(wartosc,startpoint); // miejsce to global variable
    file.seekg (miejsce+1, file.beg);
    for(p=0;(int)element<58;p++)
    {
      file.get(element);
       if((int)element>58 || (int)element<48)
      break;
      else
      buffer[p] = element;  
    }  
    buffer[p]='\0';

   g = atoi(buffer);

    delete [] buffer;
    return g;    
}

int main()
{
    int a,h=0,channels,start=0,length=0,resolution=0,bytespix=0,m=0;
    const char* slowko="Data offset: ";

    dlugosc=fileopen();

    channel** kanaly=0;
    kanaly = new channel*[9];
    miejsce=0;

    for(a=0;a<9;a++)
    {
        kanaly[a] = new channel(4);
        start = findvalue("Data offset: ",miejsce+20);  
        kanaly[a]->start=start;  
    }

    for(m=0;m<9;m++)
    {
        delete kanaly[m];
    }
    delete []kanaly;

    file.close();
}
```

Comment: @BЈовић seems to have solved the problem, but for future reference it's important to learn to construct a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @djf - I did and nothing changes.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is in the constructor of `channel`. Initialize all member variables, and the problem will go away :

```
class channel
{
public:
    double start;
    double length;
    int bytespix;
    int resolution;
    channel(double g) : start(g),
                        length(0),
                        bytespix(0),
                        resolution(0)
    {
    } 
};
```

Comment: Are there lines in the code the OP posted that depend on these uninitialised values?  Or are you assuming that the problem is in code we haven't been shown and is caused by the lack of initialisation in `channel`'s ctor?  (Not questioning that this is the solution.  Just curious because I couldn't see any problems in the code that was posted.)

Comment: @simonc You do not need to use those values to get that valgrind warning. No, the problem is in the showed code. He really didn't initialize those member variables.

Comment: Ok, I did as you wrote and unfortunately valgrind errors are the same.

Comment: @BЈовић I understand that he didn't initialse the variables and agree that it is correct to initialise them.  I'm skeptical that this is the cause of the error though.  In my experience you do have to use variables - e.g. `if (channel.length == 0)` - to get that warning.  Valgrind won't (can't) warn about memory that is allocated, never initialised and never dereferenced.

Comment: @user2455862 Most likely from a code you didn't show. Can you put full example with vagrind errors?

Comment: I would be really grateful if you could help me. This program is very important,I'm stuck and have no clue where is the problem.